# Draw Line between two points and extend the line on both sides

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below code which allows me to draw a line between the two given points. What i need to do is extend these lines both ways so that the line extends to the end in the same angle both sides of the line

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Add(new Panel{Left = 10, Top = 10,Width = 50,Height = 50, BackColor = Color.Blue});
    this.Controls.Add(new Panel {Left = 100, Top = 100,Width = 50,Height = 50, BackColor = Color.Blue});


}
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Graphics g;
    g = e.Graphics;
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    myPen.Width = 1;
    g.DrawLine(myPen, 12, 12, 45, 65);
    g.DrawLine(myPen, 100, 100, 45, 65);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I wonder why `Graphics g; g = e.Graphics;`, you are working with C#, you don't have to first declare then assign, the normal is to do both in one statement

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto never mind, I miss understood your point :D

Comment: The question is slightly unclear. What have you tried and what's not working? How far past the two points do you need the line to extend? Are the `Panel`s your points (they're rather large for points at 50x50 pixels)? Are you looking for help with the math of determining the points rather than just trying different coordinates until you get what you want? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54828076/edit) to provide further detail.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*to the end*", but you can use the slope-intercept formula to find any point on a line, so [use the distance forumula](https://www.chilimath.com/lessons/intermediate-algebra/distance-formula/) to find *the end*, and the [slope-intercept formula](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/formulating-linear-equations/writing-linear-equations-using-the-slope-intercept-form) to solve for coordinates.

Comment: Draw us a picture with labels that shows us what you want.  You could it in Paint or PowerPoint, for instance.

Comment: Note that all drawing is __below__ all controls! E.g.: use  `Color semiBlue = Color.FromArgb(66, Color.Blue);` for your panels! - One way to draw 'to the end' would be until you hit s a border/edge of the current canvas; another to draw to 'infinity' or to a really large values of one coordinate. Some (basic) math is always required.

Comment: Here is how to draw a long line through and beyond two points p1 and p2: `float a = p1.X == p2.X ? 90 :
    (float)Math.Atan(p1.Y - p2.Y )/ (p1.X - p2.X); 
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(p2.X, p2.Y);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(a);
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-p2.X, -p2.Y);
g.DrawLine(Pens.Turquoise, -111, -111, 1111, 1111);
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();`

Comment: Note: Per SO rules when posting a question here __you are expected__ to stick around and answer all questions regarding clarification!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes you are right, no need for a separate line of code. i will change the code

Comment: @Crowcoder to the end means that i need to draw a line which extends from the 2 given points to the end of the border/panel on which the 2 points are given

Comment: @TaW YEs i am trying the solution provided by you, few changes needed as per my customization. Will surely update once i get through. Thanks

Comment: @TaW Sorry TaW i will make sure that i try and reply to all the comments.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, will provide my updates once i am through with the solution

Comment: Note that the 111 was a typo meant to be 1111 and really meant a number 'larger than the target size'.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the method:

startPoint and endPoint  are famous points. p1 and p2 are new start and end points.

```
 public static void FindSimmetricPointsOnLine(Point startPoint, Point endPoint, double distance, out Point p1, out Point p2)
        {
            p1 = new Point();
            p2 = new Point();
            var xa = startPoint.X;
            var ya = startPoint.Y;
            var xb = endPoint.X;
            var yb = endPoint.Y;
            var l = distance;
            double x1 = 0;
            double x2 = 0;
            double y1 = 0;
            double y2 = 0;


            if (xa == xb)
            {
                x1 = x2 = xa;
                y1 = ya + l;
                y2 = ya - l;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ya == yb)
                {
                    y1 = y2 = ya;
                    x1 = xa + l;
                    x2 = xa - l;
                }
                else
                {
                    var K = (ya - yb)/(xa - xb);
                    var B = ya - K*xa;
                    var A1 = K*K + 1;
                    var B1 = -2*(xa + K*(ya - B));
                    var C1 = xa*xa + (ya - B)*(ya - B) - l*l;
                    var D = B1*B1 - 4*A1*C1;

                    if (D >= 0)
                    {
                        x1 = (-B1 + Math.Sqrt(D))/(2*A1);
                        x2 = (-B1 - Math.Sqrt(D))/(2*A1);


                        y1 = K*x1 + B;
                        y2 = K*x2 + B;

                        p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
                        p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code that should do what you need.

```
public void ExtendLine(Point p1, Point p2, double distance, out Point start, out Point end)
{
    //first find the vector that represents the direction of the line
    Vector direction = p2 - p1;

    //normalize the vector to a distance of one point
    direction.Normalize();

    //multiply the direction by to total distance to find the offset amount
    Vector offset = (direction * distance);

    //subtract the offset from the start point to find the new start point
    start = p1 - offset;

    //add the offset to the end point to find the new end point
    end = p2 + offset;
}
```

Here is an example showing how to use the method.

```
Point p1 = new Point(Line1.X1, Line1.Y1), p2 = new Point(Line1.X2, Line1.Y2);
ExtendLine(p1, p2, 10, out Point p3, out Point p4);
Line2.X1 = p3.X;
Line2.Y1 = p3.Y;
Line2.X2 = p4.X;
Line2.Y2 = p4.Y;
```